# Question About Dimensions and Figures Surrounding A Pressurised Nitrogen Canister

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, material-science

I need a nitrogen gas canister that will nitrogenate a beverage much like how SodaStream carbonates. Here are some approximate numbers:
The beverage to nitrogenate is 600 - 1000 mL
I want to be able to nitrogenate this beverage about 10-20 times before refilling the cannister (similar level of nitrogenation as SodaStream carbonates)
I want to minimise the volume of the cannister since I want to have a total volume that is reasonable to lug around with you

Here's what I need know:
What kind of pressures am I looking at in my nitrogen gas cavity?
Follow up to this, what materials are rated for these pressures and how thick would the walls have to be? I heard stainless steel is pretty tolerant.

Ask if you need more context, I am aware this probably requires a lot of background information to answer properly.
[image: the construction of the container is similar to that of a double walled thermos]

Also, is it possible to store nitrogen as a liquid for higher pressures in smaller volume or too hard to do?

Comment: Consider that (dry) air is mostly (but not overwhelmingly) nitrogen.  Because of this, you may have some luck just producing the pressurized nitrogen as needed... use ideal gas approximation for pressures.  You may wish to look into nitrogen solubility in your fluid...